# Bootstrap 4 Colorpicker - Force refresh of all color pickers

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, color-picker

I'm using the Bootstrap 4 color picker library:

https://itsjavi.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/

I have color pickers defined as follows:

```
       <div class="input-group cpicker">
           <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" value="#000000" id="txtModalDashboardSettings_HeaderColor">
           <span class="input-group-append">
               <span id="cp_dashboardHeaderColor" class="input-group-text colorpicker-input-addon"><i></i></span>
           </span>
       </div>
```

I use the following javascript to create the Bootstrap 4 colorpicker:

```
$('.cpicker').colorpicker();
```

The colors are programatically changed at some point in the code.  However, calling the $('.cpicker').colorpicker() again does not update the colorpicker color.

How can I force all of the the colorpickers to refresh/update if I changed the input value programatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but I manage to do it as follows.  It is not ideal as I need to update each colorpicker individually:

```
$('colorPickerId').colorpicker('setValue', '#color');
```